# How to add scripts to a site collection without modifying the masterpage

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page

Our company has restricted any modifications to 2013 SharePoint masterpages.  For the most part I have been using layout pages to add scripts however if a site is not a publishing site, I am looking at other methods to perform this function.  Even layout pages do not effect a collection but just the pages that are associated.

So my question is how can I add or inject scripts into the masterpage without touching it.  Visual Studio method has also been shutdown to us.  Any advice would be wonderful.  PS: I am a novice coder, more designer.

thanks so much
CSM

Comment: Search for UserCustomAction Scriptlinks... But even seasoned SharePoint programmers hardly use them.. so you need decent programming skills

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.   I will give UserCustomAction ScriptLinks a try and also see if one of our programmers can assist.   If you encounter any other options, please post.  I will check back.  Best regards..... csm

Answer (score 4):

#### Some tools that make adding Script easier:

- (Chrome Browser Extension) [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)
  Edit CSR files with Live Updating
- (Chrome Browser Extension) [Chrome SP Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd/related?hl=en)
  Edit SharePoint files, add ScriptLinks to SiteCollection/Webs, manage Web Property Bag
- add an ASPX Page (so works in any Browser) and manage [UserCustomActions](https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the pnp power shell commands. can easily inject a script on every page of your site. i use it all the time on a 2013 site. works great. the command is add-sposcriptlink or something like that.

Comment: Hi there,   thanks much for the info on the power shell command option.
Question:   If I create a GblScript.js file and have the server admin inject the script into the Seattle masterpage.... I am assuming that the process will not need to be repeated.  I can just manage everything in the scripts file then....thoughts/suggestions?   thanks much CSM

Comment: yes, that's right.