# Custom Status Indicator Column in JSLink attached to Content Type?

Tags: javascript, content-type, jslink

I'm looking to add a custom Status Indicator column to records within a document library, which would show an image depending on a field's value. "Pass = Tick.jpg", "Fail = Cross.jpg", that kind of thing. I'm currently trying to do this with JS Link, and I have a couple of questions about implementation.

Firstly, is there a way to make sure the Template override appears in *all* iterations of the column? I want it to appear in web parts and the list view, but not necessarily forms.

Secondly, I'd like to include the column for the Status Indicator in different Content Types. Is this possible so my custom status images appear site-wide?

Thirdly, Can this override be applied in a way that it automatically applies to new sub-sites created, where the same column/content types appear?

Basically, I'm trying to apply my JS Link as a blanket rule if possible. In plain text, the behaviour should be "Wherever this column appears in the site (and sub-sites), replace the text with a correspoinding image".

I'm just beginning with JS Link, so any links to explainers/feature lists would be useful too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand a bit on what Danny is saying in his answer:

Yes, JSLink is the technology you use to "attach" a JavaScript file to something in SharePoint.  That "something" could be many things - typically through the UI you see it in the web part settings for List View Web Parts or Form web parts.

However, other "things" in SharePoint also have a JSLink property, and specifically relevant to your question, site columns have a JSLink property.

If you are defining your column declaratively with CAML, you can set the JSLink attribute this way:

```
<Field ID="{8C7EF15E-264E-4766-BDC9-405CD1D5985B}"
       Name="MyField"
       DisplayName="My Field"
       Type="Text"
       JSLink="~sitelayouts/Path/To/My/CSRScript.js"
       Group="My Custom Columns" />
```

If you have created your fields through the UI, you would need to use Powershell to set the JSLink property, but it can be done.

Here's [a good article](https://zimmergren.net/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013/) that shows a few ways to set JSLink properties.

So the point is, if you create your site column at the site collection level, and set the JSLink property of that top level site column to attach your script, then yes, the script will follow that column around wherever it is used - in any content types, and in any subsites.

As far as whether your CSR override will be applied in list views vs. forms, that is done within the CSR script itself.  Typically CSR scripts are structured like this:

```
var renderingOverride = {};
renderingOverride.Templates = {};
renderingOverride.Templates.Fields = {    
    'MyFieldInternalName': { 
        View: functionToRenderInListViews,
        DisplayForm: functionToRenderInTheDisplayForm,
        EditForm: functionToRenderInTheEditForm,
        NewForm: functionToRenderInTheNewForm
    } 
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(renderingOverride);
```

So yes, you absolutely can specify how the field is rendered in each of the different forms and in list views.

Here is [a great primer](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/620110/sharepoint-client-side-rendering-list-views) on Client Side Rendering.

Comment: +1 , I forgot about the Powershell/Site Column part... only do things that can be done Client-Side... raises the question... What is the execution order? UserCustomActions execute first.. but then? I presume WebPart JSLinks load after SiteColumn JSLinks..

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Can you give me some more info on how to set the SPField of a custom column? The CSR primer was great for understanding the structure of the JS file needed, I just need to know how to get it into the right place so that my custom column is always displayed correctly.

Comment: @MarkE are you creating the custom column through CAML or did you create it just through the regular SharePoint UI?  If you made it in CAML, you can see my example above.  If you made it through the UI, you will have to use Powershell to set the JSLink.  There is an example in the other article I linked to of what that might look like.  If you are not able to use Powershell, Danny's idea of using a UserCustomAction to get the script on every page is probably a good option.  However I can't give an example of that as I've never done that.

Comment: Al these methods do the same, they execute JavaScript **before** SharePoint does its own rendering. ScriptLinks can easily be managed with: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210752/how-to-add-scripts-to-a-site-collection-without-modifying-the-masterpage/210762#210762

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Yes,

Yes,

But let's start with the Basics... You are doing CSR (Client Side Rendering) **not** JSLink

JSLink is the technology to link a scriptfile to a WebPart.
This can be any JS file (or even loading jQuery from a CDN) it doesn't have to be a CSR file

Instead of linking your CSR file with JSLink you can load your CSR file as a UserCustomAction.

That way it gets executed on every page. Your Field Overrides are applied everywhere the internal name is used:

Yes, a User Custom Action executes on every page

Yes, Field Overrides work by Internal names

Yes, A SiteCollection scoped UserCustomAction will execute on every page in the SiteCollection. A Web Scoped UCA will only execute within one site and **not** its subsites

---

- https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar
  makes CSR editing a breeze, but it creates JSlinks
- https://github.com/tavikukko/Chrome-SP-Editor
  Will help create UserCustomActions (link them to the files created with Cisar)

---

Note: CSR, JSLink , UserCustomActions will **not** work in SharePoint Online "Modern" Experiences. Microsoft disabled all branding

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about UserCustomActions? Is it just a js file placed differently within the Sharepoint architecture? If you could point me to a beginners guide or something similar, it would be very helpful. Why won't it work with SharePoint Online? It would be preferable for my needs if it did.